# Is there any way in sqlmap(sql-injection testing tool) to fetch database tables without running the complete test?

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap

Is there any way in sqlmap(sql-injection testing tool) to fetch database tables without running the complete test?

When I test a URL it takes a long time to Complete the whole test and retrieve database tables. Is there any shorter way to do fetch database or database tables ?